# How to prepend String on each line by jline3?

Tags: java, jline3

I want app to print on each line its name like (`shell >` ):

```
shell > --param1 value1 --param2 value2
```

Is it possible to implement it by jline3?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jline3-terminal.
It has support for 'jansi' and 'jna'. Both work near same, but jansi is a bit light weight than jna. Whereas jna is more generic.

You can follow documentation [here](https://github.com/jline/jline3) and the also the terminal documentation [here](https://github.com/jline/jline3/wiki/Terminals).

Prefer maven project to start with and go ahead with documentation.

Let me know for anything else.

Comment: I can't find anything about prepending string to the command line in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

See JLine [readLine()](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.jline/jline/3.17.1/org.jline/org/jline/reader/LineReader.html#readLine-java.lang.String-java.lang.Character-java.lang.String-) javadoc. Add command prompt (`shell >`) to your CLI app call `readLine` method as

```
lineReader.readLine("shell > ", null, null);
```

If you want to add buffer also the default value for user to edit call `readLine` method as

```
lineReader.readLine("shell > ", null, "--param1 value1 --param2 value2");
```